# "Runtime error 380: invalid property value"

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

When I click the Export button on the spreadsheet, it exports information to C:\IMPORT.TXT

I then imports it into a label program. From there, print the labels.

The error it comes up with is "Runtime error 380: invalid property value" when I press Export

I've attached the spreadsheet. If you click on the worksheet Tesco or Friends, you will see an Export button.

I'm not sure if you can sort this without having the label software, but you might be able to view the macro code and see where it is failing?

[Attached file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ncvtu9py42zm7lc/Monday.xlsm?dl=0) Here.

Thank you.

```
Option Explicit

Dim MojeF As ExcelExtras.Functions
Public Sub FileSend()
On Error Resume Next
    Dim wynik As String

    If MojeF Is Nothing Then Set MojeF = New ExcelExtras.Functions
    wynik = MojeF.FileTes(Application)
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Tab.ColorIndex = 10

End Sub
Public Sub SendTesco()
Call SendIt("Tesco", "TESCO")
End Sub
Public Sub SendFr()
Call SendIt("Friends", "FRIENDPR")
End Sub
Public Sub SendConv()
Call SendIt("Con", "CONVEN")
End Sub
Public Sub SendStat()
Call SendIt("Station", "STATIONG")
End Sub

Public Sub SendIt(arkusz As String, kodd As String)
Dim wynik As String

    If MojeF Is Nothing Then Set MojeF = New ExcelExtras.Functions
 '   wynik = MojeF.SendIt(Application, arkusz, kodd, "a.txt - Notepad")
    wynik = MojeF.SendIt(Application, arkusz, kodd, "Sage Line 50 Financial Controller - Gourmet Productions Limited")
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(arkusz).Tab.ColorIndex = -4142

End Sub

Private Sub auto_open()
Dim aktywny As Integer

For aktywny = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
If Len(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(aktywny).Name) > 1 And ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(aktywny).Name <> "Stand" And ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(aktywny).Name <> "Deluxe" Then ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(aktywny).Tab.ColorIndex = 3

Next

 End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is giving the error?

Comment: The `ExcelExtras` reference is in the project References list in the file you shared, but is flagged (of course) as "Missing".

Comment: @TimWilliams [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f9xbgf3yqnbimb3/ExcelExtras.dll?dl=0) is  the dll file if you want to have a look